# DataGridView CheckboxColumn header check box synchronize with rows?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have made a checkbox inside the header of checkbox column. It works fine when i check it all rows in the `DataGridView` gets checked. What I want to do is to uncheked the header cell checkbox when a single row in the DataGridView is unchecked. I tried putting code in the `CellValueChanged` event that sets the header checkbox state. The problem is that `CellValueChanged` is fired when current cell loses focus. So if I click two or three times in the cell nothing happens, but when `e` select next cell the event is fired and the header cell checkbox state is invalidated.

Answer (score 4):

In CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged event call the datagridview's CommitEdit(DataGridViewErrorContexts.Commit) method.
It commits the cell value and triggers the CellValueChanged event of corresponding cell.

Answer (score 0):

tried CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged event?

Comment: Yes i Have tried using it but when this event fires the new value of the cell is not yet set. So the cell has it's old value and i must presume  the new value will be the opposite of current value. But i have form where in cell_validating or in cell_endedit value of cell is changed.